# Search values in datagrid without using data set vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am inserting values in datagrid from MS-SQL server. I got a text box from which i wanted to perform search operation , but the thing is i haven't used data set.
the question is How do i search for values in datagrid without using data set in vb.net.
Here is my code fr filling up data grid view.

```
    dim i as integer = 0
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MY_CONNECTION_STRING "
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("selct ID, Name From tbl_name where 1=1 Order by Name ASC", con)
        con.Open()
                   ' Execute Query
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        '  Try
        While reader.Read()
            DataGridView10.Rows.Insert(i, New String() {reader(0), reader(1).ToString})
            i = i + 1
        End While
```

Comment: What do you want to search? For ex: columns or rows for data?

Comment: i want to search rows for data. basically i want to get id of searched  element for example search name "XYZ" and get ID associated with it.

Comment: Do you want the cell highlighted or just the row?

Comment: i want to height the cell

Comment: Ok got it...Im answering now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in a click event per say...

```
  Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim intIndex As Integer = SearchGrid(TextBox1.Text, 0) 'Change the 0 to what column you want to search for
    DataGridView1.Rows(intIndex).Selected = True 'This will select the row...'
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(intIndex).Cells(0) 'This ensures that the arrow will move if you have row headers visible. In order to select the cell change the zero to the column your searching to match up top
  End Sub
```

Here's the function...

```
  Private Function SearchGrid(ByVal strItem As String, ByVal intColumn As Integer) As Integer
    Dim intIndex As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(intColumn).Value.ToString.Contains(strItem) Then 'Or change "Contains" to "Equals"
            intIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return intIndex
End Function
```

This will work great for you and a great start, happy coding!

P.S. Make sure to change the datagridview name to reflect yours...

Comment: See edits... If you want just the cell, make sure to match the 0's. for example you are searching the 1st column (0), make sure both spots have a 0 in them ...